# Get device or serial port use count

Tags: linux, serial-port

Is there any way to get the number of programs that have opened a file descriptor (in this case serial port)?

I want to know if somebody is connected to the serial port, and if yes, how many programs.

I want to do so in linux.

TA

Answer (score 0):

I believe fuser should do the trick.